# What's the best way to keep sushi fresh for the following day?

Tags: sushi, fresh

I like to prepare makizushi in the night so that I can take it in to Uni the following day and have it for lunch. They're made using nori, sushi rice and some vegetables.

What's the best way to keep this fresh for the following day - I normally box them up the night before ready for the day?

Answer (score 6):

I think the issue is that your nori will get soggy if you make the rolls in advance and store them overnight.  Nigirizushi may be a better bet for making ahead.

Chirashizushi is an older style of sushi which is essentially a bowl of the sushi rice, with the garnishes either mixed in or on top. It should be well amenable to advance preparation.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, the nori is the problem as it gets a bit wet. I think leaving the rice to cool well might be a solution

Answer (score 4):

The trick I've seen used in Asia is to place a sheet of plastic or cling wrap between the rice and the nori. For example, you could make a long roll with several layers like so:

- plastic (outermost layer)
- nori
- plastic
- rice
- other ingredients

Roll it up in a long roll, and when you want to eat it, 'jerk' the inner layer of plastic out, thus allowing you to eat it. One problem you'll probably face is the inner layer sticking to the rice. A light application of vegetable oil on the side of the plastic sheet facing the rice might help with this.

Answer (score 4):

If you are making maki sushi or other sushi with nori on the outside, then the simple trick is too roll or wrap it in baking paper (or plastic film, or waxed paper) just as you would with a sheet of nori. And stack them in an air-tight box or bag in the refrigerator until needed

Then just before serving unwrap carefully and wrap some nori around them as required. *Perfect sushi made earlier!*